# session[:user_id] is changing from nil to previous value on browser go back button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In my rails app , when I logout , in the `destroy` method I am setting `session[:user_id]=nil`. But when I press back button on the browser the `session[:user_id]` gets back its previous value and it is automatically showing the logged in page. Why is this happening? How do I make the `session[:user_id]=nil` persistent till I change it?

session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_posts_path
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
   session[:user_id] = nil
  end

end
```

application.html.erb

```
<% if !(session[:user_id].nil?)%>
    Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>
    <%= link_to 'Log Out', session_path(current_user), :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
    <% if current_page?(new_user_path) %>
        <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %>
    <% elsif current_page?(login_path)  %>
        <%= link_to "sign up",new_user_path%>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Log in", login_path %>
        <%= link_to "sign up",new_user_path%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>
```

there is no error in the `rails s` console.

last message on the console.

```
Started DELETE "/sessions/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-08 00:23:11 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"B0QLdVrsV9ZgwjS/Y8qVb3ID0q9gsC2peFQAZ/0J638kUTpXcAYcg1I+ulX1UaLujr4C7NPgIann74UETMOz6w==", "id"=>"2"}
  Rendered sessions/destroy.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 144ms (Views: 143.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Please add the server log and the controller. I'm suspecting that your action may not be run at all.

Comment: @max : edited the question

Comment: You have quite a few oddities going on here. Sessions should be singular resource. So the logout path should be `DESTROY /sessions` without an id. Why do you have a `sessions/destroy.html.erb` view? You should be redirecting instead - use a flash message to notify the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reset_session` in your logout action instead. This will issue a new session identifier and declare the old one invalid and prevents other session fixation based attacks.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures

**This is a run through of how to setup your SessionsController properly:**

Sessions are not really like a standard crud resource where you have the full range of CRUD verbs and fetch records from the database.

From a user standpoint there are only three actions:

```
new - displays the login form
create - verifies the credentials and signs the user in.
destroy - logs user out by resetting the session.
```

Change your routes definition to treat Sessions as a singular resource:

```
resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Then we are going to create a helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    @user ||= User.find!(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def can_sign_in?
    user_signed_in? || current_page?(new_user_path) || current_page?(new_session_path)
  end 
end
```

This way the actual implementation of how the user is stored in the session is only in one place in your application and not spread all over your controllers and views.

Lets make sure we can call it from our controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Then lets remedy the controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /session
  def new
  end

  # POST /session
  def create
    reset_session # prevents sessions fixation!
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_posts_path 
    else 
      render 'new', flash: "Invalid username or password."
    end
  end

  # DELETE /session
  def destroy
   reset_session 
   if user_signed_in?
     flash[:notice] = 'You have been signed out successfully.'
   else 
     flash[:error] = 'You are not signed in!'
   end
   redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

`application.html.erb`

```
<%= render partial: 'sessions/actions' %>
<%= yield %>
```

We use a partial since the application layout tends to turn into a monster.
`sessions/_actions.html.erb`.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>
  <%= link_to 'Log Out', session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Log in', new_session_path if can_sign_in? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There is the advanced case where you store sessions in the database and might want to display the currently logged in user for example but i think that might be a bit over your head currently.